# Smallest quasi-pangrammatic number

Tags: english, pangram

A quasi-pangrammatic number is a positive integer whose English name contains at least one copy of each letter used to write all of the positive integers that precede it.

123456789 (*"one hundred twenty-three million four hundred fifty-six thousand seven hundred eighty-nine"*) is a quasi-pangrammatic number: its name contains all letters execept for *b*, *c*, *j*, *k*, *p*, *q* and *z*, and no other letters are needed to write integers from 1 to 123456788 in words.

The smallest quasi-pangrammatic number is trivially 1 (*"one"*) because there are no positive integers before it.

What is the smallest quasi-pangrammatic integer after 1?

Comment: I guess you want the ENGLISH quasi-pangrammatic number? Although it would be interesting to see, which language provides the smallest number... Bonus question ;c)

Comment: @BmyGuest [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirah%C3%A3_language#Numerals_and_grammatical_number) for the bonus question ;-)

Comment: nb. in British English number names contain additional uses of the word "and", like "one hundred and one". Not sure if that affects your answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Thanks to @dmg for the correction*

I think the answer is

> 12,468 (twelve thousand four hundred sixty eight). It covers the letters: adefghilnorstuvwxy.

Why I think it is the answer?

> I wrote down the letters that come in the English names of 1,2....19,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90. I chose these numbers only because other numbers will just repeat. For example in sixty two, I have already considered 'sixty' and 'two' separately. Now the letters that I wrote were: ONETWHRFUIVSXGLY. I had to take 8 in my smallest number because it is the only number that has a G. 12 for L and W. 4 or 5 for F. I chose four because it is smaller. 6 for X.

Comment: The same set of letters is generated by 12468. Otherwise a perfect approach!

Comment: @dmg Then i am afraid my answer is wrong. I forgot that 12 also have L in it. You should post it as answer.

Comment: It's a minor mistake, your approach is correct, so I suggest you simply edit the number.

Comment: @dmg Thanks for the approval. Corrected

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a little proramm to check the numbers from one to one million for this property and there turn out to be 817 such numbers.

> I also checked it for German and due to äöüß there is no such number in the first million besides 1, so I replaced them with ae,oe,ue,ss and 721. With the smallest being 12,467, just one below the English one.

The smallest common number ($\neq 1$) in English and German is 412,678.

Here is a little plot of them:

[image]

**Edit:**

> In the meantime I also calculated the smallest German quasi-pangrammatic number using the correct spelling (with äöüß) and it turns out to be 4,512,637

Comment: That was the same number Manshu got - however, you failed to account for the fact that 12 is written "twelve". Nice work though!

Comment: I think I don't understand your comment. Isn't 12,468 the right answer?

Comment: You said the answer was 412678.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I guess my text isn't clear enough. 412678 is the smallest quasi pangramatic number that exists in both English and German (with the write letters). Besides that I get manshu's result. :)